# Pattern finding algorithms

Tags: algorithms, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

I am working on a server that will update a list each day. The list will look like the following example.

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |     A      |      B      |      C      |      D      |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Name1      |      1      |      2      |     true    |
| 2 | Name2      |      2      |      3      |     true    |
| 3 | Name3      |      1      |      1      |     false   |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

In this example I only used 2 table (except for the name) but in the real list there are 15 columns, with each containing other numbers (some columns can also have the same value).

I also have a last column that is filled with value true or false. This column will be filled on the next day that i receive the other values.

What I want to program is a algorithm that will be able to search through the data that I already have for a pattern(s) that is most common for all the row's with the value true.

I have no idea how I am able to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Data Mining problem; specifically, the problem of Frequent Pattern Mining. If you want to find various frequent itemsets given a transaction database, then you'll probably be interested in algorithms such as [Apriori](http://www.borgelt.net/apriori.html) and [FP-Growth](http://www.borgelt.net/fpgrowth.html).